# Find the inverse of the function given:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$f(x)= \frac{5x}{(x − 2)}$$

My work:

$$y=\frac{5x}{(x-2)}$$

$$x=\frac{5y}{(y-2)}$$

$$x(y-2)=5y$$

$$xy-2x=5y$$

$$\frac{xy-2x}{5}=y$$

$$f(x)=\frac{(xy-2x)}{5}$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: While you have found an *implicit* formulation of the inverse (kind of), your last "good" step was $xy - 2x = 5y$. How would you solve $3y - 6 = 5y$? It's equivalent to what you had if $x = 3$, and hopefully helps you see what to do instead. Also, make sure when you're done that you don't write $f(x) = \ldots$, but instead $f^{-1}(x) = \ldots\ $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solve for $x$ in $y=\frac{5x}{x-2}$:
$$
y(x-2)=5x\\
\Downarrow\\
yx-5x=2y\\
\Downarrow\\
x(y-5)=2y\\
\Downarrow\\
x=\frac{2y}{y-5}
$$
This implies the inverse is $f(x)=\frac{2x}{x-5}$.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot.

Comment: @TheNewGuy You're welcome! I glad it helped. :)